# expected something between the beginning of the request and the 'IF' keyword error when using IF in TeraData

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I am trying to make a "drop if exist" in TeraData with the following statement

```
SELECT 1 
FROM DBC.TABLES 
WHERE DatabaseName = 'test1'
  AND TableName = 'test2';
  

IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN .GOTO l2; -- no result, skip SQL 1

DROP TABLE test1.test2;

.EXIT;  -- don't run SQL2

.LABEL l2;

   IF hNoAccts = 1 THEN
     INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (hNoAccts, 'One Customer');
   END IF;
END
```

But I got the error "Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the 'IF' keyword."
I also tried with ".IF" but I got the same error.
Does anyone know how to do the drop if exist or why this error is occurring?
Thankss

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL, please don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you are trying to, but your syntax is off.  You need to use `.IF` and `.ENDIF`  (leading period)

Comment: `IF hNoAccts = 1 THEN` will not work outside of a Stored Procedure. To drop a table if it exists see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65716399/2527905

Comment: Also: when using "multi-instruction" IF / ELSEIF / ELSE / ENDIF syntax there should be no THEN keyword.